# ExtJS AJAX get raw response text

Tags: ajax, json, extjs, extjs4.2

I am making an AJAX call in ExtJS 4, which some users have reported fails without showing any error messages. Looking at the response object, the code is 0 and the responseText is blank. My best guess is that the server is for some reason returning something that is not properly formatted as JSON.

How can I get the raw response text if it is not formatted as JSON?

Comment: It is `responseText` the raw text. Most probably tt is blank, because the server send you no response body. Install FireBug and see what is sent back to your browser to make sure.

Comment: Unfortunately Firebug is not an option - I have been unable to replicate the problem, and the users that have gotten the error, I'm lucky to get a screenshot from.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `Ext.data.Connection` to grab the data when it is returned, and before it is processed in any way. I would guess that Andrei is right with his diagnosis, but if you aren't so sure...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get everything you need like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : 'someUrl',
listeners : {
    requestexception : function( conn, response, options, eOpts ){
    console.log(response);
    }

}
});
```

Status 0 should give you Communication Failure in response.operation.error.statusText ... just console.log(response) and start looking for the significant property for you I wouldn't go to raw unless no other option.

Regards.